# Since when Disks statistics in `top` command are counted?

Tags: osx, disk, top, statistics

I've got these disk statistics shown in `top` command:

```
$ top | head | tail -n1
Disks: 1095425909/52T read, 1016012571/52T written.
```

It's quiet high number for *only* 37 day uptime.

Are these numbers are counted since the boot time, or another period? I can't find it in the documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `top` command tries to report statistics since boot time when it only reports one set; if it's set to report on a loop basis (e.g. with the `-d` option), the first report is since boot, the second and thereafter are for the most recent loop period only.